# What is this Pop Up Screen on Cardano Documentation?

Tags: plutus, documentation

When searching the docs it helps to use `ctrl` + `F` to find something fast, however, when I use it on the plutus docs I get a weird pop-up screen I'm not used to. (Image Below)

My Questions are:

1. What is this screen?
2. Why does it pop up?
3. Can It help me in any way / what use does it have?
4. Is there a way to stop it from poping up?

link to a page this has happened on: https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V1-Ledger-Contexts.html

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What is this screen?

that window comes by default with the haddock documentation

I think it should work as a quick "go-to" however for PlutusTx the links do never work (at least to my experience)

### Why does it pop up?

by pressing `Ctrl`+`F` you are searching for some text in the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) of the page

that window is located on top of the main content at the ```ħtml`` level so the search goes there first

### Can It help me in any way / what use does it have?

It can give you a quick overview of what's on the page however the clicking on the Types usually doesn't work so it's not that useful

### Is there a way to stop it from poping up?

not by the webpage functionalities but you can remove it from the page by running the following javascript code in the browser console

> you can open the browser console by pressing `F12` or  `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J` or by the three dots on the top left of the browser searching for `Developer tools`

```
document.getElementById("synopsis").remove()
```

this will remove the window only for the current page, refreshing or re-access the page will have the window once again